# Фон картинкой в CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, background, background-image

Всем привет:) Не могу фон сделать под размер страницы, постоянно фон как бы не помещается на страницу. Все говорят про **background-size: cover;** Но он у меня никогда нормально не работал.
Так же пробовал задавать высоту и ширину родительскому блоку, **width: 100%; width: 1920px;** . Так же работает не так как нужно.

Единственное что мне нравится так это **background-size: contain;** Но при уменьшении страницы он уменьшает высоту.

Готов выслушать вашу критику:)

```css
.block-advantage-price {
  background: #0b2f58 url("https://yapx.ru/v/F3BQX") no-repeat top center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-advantage-price">
    <div class="advantage-info">
      <h3>Ищите конкретную деталь?</h3>
      <p>Если у Вас есть артикул - введите его в поле ниже и получите цену <br> ПРЯМО СЕЙЧАС!</p>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="POST" id="form-advantage-price">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Введите артикул детали" title="Введите артикул детали">
      <input type="tel" id="telephone" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" pattern="2[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}"
        title="Введите ваш номер телефона" required>
      <input type="submit" value="УЗНАТЬ ЦЕНУ">
    </form>
    <div class="advantage-info">
      <p>Мы перезвоним вам в течении 3 минут и назовем цену детали!</p>
      <p>Или вы можете перезвонить нам сами:</p>
      <a href="tel:+78182474725"> +7 (XX8) 2XX-X7-X5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Примеры (Прошу прошение за качество):
[image: Как должно выглядеть]
Рисунок 1 - Как должен выглядеть фон

[image: При background-size: cover;]
Рисунок 2 - При background-size: cover

[image: При background-size: contain]
Рисунок 3 - При background-size: contain[image: При background-size: 100% 100%;]
Рисунок 4 - При background-size: 100% 100%

Как видим по ширине адекватно отображается только **background-size: contain;** Но по высоте работает не корректно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

background-size:cover 
ведет себя так, как должен, он не может у кого то работать,у кого-то нет. Если у вас есть блок выше, который обеспечивает этот синий фон, вероятно он больше вашего родительского элемента. Узнать это очень просто:
background-color:red
Если красная область будет такая же как и на вашем изображении с background-size:cover, значит ваш блок меньше размером, чем родитель.

UPD:

```css
.block-advantage-price{
background-image:url("https://yapx.ru/v/F3BQX");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:top center;
background-size:cover;
}
```

[Залил код сюда](https://codepen.io/mrageslf/pen/gObpQWe)
Отпишите, если это тот эффект, которого вы добивались

Comment: Фон я задаю конкретно для родительского блока. Изменив фон на background: red; Изменится весь фон. Так же попробовал ввести background-color:red; для родительского блока и ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Попробуйте задать картинку через background-image, а фон (который синий цвет ваш) перекинуть в родителя. Повторное background-size уберите, оставьте только background-size:cover.

Comment: насчет разделить картинку на 3 части , как по мне безумная идея

Comment: А при изменении размеров экрана вы фоновое изображение будете так же по куска масштабировать? А если блоки будут разного размера к примеру? Или на планшете эти блоки нужно будет выстроить в колонну? Вариант не плохой, но не думаю, что он хорош для этой реализации. Хотя тут у каждого своя правда насчёт реализаций. Так что с безумием я конечно погорячился.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте Ваш фон из трех частей, предварительно разрезав картинку на эти самые нужные три части. Это единственный в Вашем случае будет вариант, который полностью решит поставленную задачу.

Comment: Может и не единственный, но самый оптимальный  если сроки поджимают.

Comment: Разделить фон на три части, что? Первый раз слышу о таком способе. Немного не понятно. Можете объяснить как для умственно отсталого. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я разделил картинку на три части, но вот не знаю к какому блоку его применить.

Answer (score 1):

Ребят, все оказалось гораздо проще.. Я просто забыл что картинку невозможно растягивать до бесконечности) Из-за некоторых ошибок в отступах (margin/padding) я получил такое "чудо". А так bg-size: cover; все решил! Всем спасибо  за помощь и советы!